# Ways to indicate TypeScript to infer type

Tags: typescript

Consider this code:

```
function Foo(num: number) {
  switch (num) {
    case 0: return { type: "Quz", str: 'string', } as const;
    case 1: return { type: "Bar", 1: 'value' } as const;
    default: throw new Error("Unknown discriminant: " + num);
  }
}
```

typescript infer this discriminated union type:

```
function Foo(num: number): 
{ readonly type: "Quz"; readonly str: "string"; readonly 1?: undefined; } |
{ readonly type: "Bar"; readonly 1: "value"; readonly str?: undefined; }
```

However I doesn't want to get the type of discriminatory union that typescript inferred, But expected this:

```
{ type: "Quz"; str: "string"; } | { type: "Bar"; 1: "value"; }
```

I don't want to specify a return type separately. Also I don't want to evaluate any of the possible outputs ahead of time.

Is there a way to hint typescript compiler to guess the type of discriminant union I expect?

Comment: @jcalz, I think he doesn't want to get the type of discriminatory union that typescript inferred. And expected this type `{ type: "Quz"; str: "string"; } | { type: "Bar"; 1: "value"; }` instead ?

Comment: That may be what xtr wants, but the question isn't being clear about it (the mention of "discriminated union" is only a distraction from the issue, since both the expected and unexpected results are discriminated unions).  I explained in the original comment that TypeScript is behaving as expected according to the documentation links.  We can't really change the way TS *infers* these types (without changing the implementation) but you can always just *annotate* the return type like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjX26m) shows.  Maybe that fully addresses xtr's question, or maybe not

Comment: @jcalz, sorry for any confusion, I've updated my question, can we return the discriminant union type without specifying a return type that I expect?

Comment: The type you are getting *is* a discriminated union. The differences between your expected and actual results are only (1) that the actual result type has `readonly` fields, and (2) that each variant has an optional field of type `undefined` indicating that that field is not present on that variant. Which of those things do you specifically not want, and why?

Comment: The title is still confusing to me; you could probably remove every instance of "discriminated union" from the title and question without losing anything of value.

Comment: I still don't understand the use case; if the type inferred by the compiler isn't what you expect, *why not* annotate what you expect?  It seems like you want some middle ground whereby you give the compiler some kind of hint to affect inference... but even if we *can* do that (maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0b8Pw) except it's still `readonly`), *why* do you want to do that? Why hint when you can just specify? Or why not just use the inferred type, which is a subtype of the expected type? What, specifically, is the use case that motivates this question?

Comment: @jcalz,  The type is too big and I don't want to describe the type separately. Could TypeScript assume the expected type? It that possible ?

Comment: And [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0b8Pw) example is not an option, because the value of the `const a` expression should not be evaluated, unless in the switch case base on `num`

Comment: I guess this is not possible (not yet) ?, But thanks for your (@jcalz) time...

Comment: So then does [this](https://tsplay.dev/N72pPw) meet your needs?  It's hard because it seems you have very specific requirements, none of which are actually mentioned in the question

Comment: @kaya3, Well lets forget about `readonly`, And my expected type and type that typescript Inferred are different. I hope it answer you question ?

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer, but could you [edit] the question to mention the requirements you've put in the comments?  (e.g., you don't want to have to write out the expected type anywhere, you don't want to evaluate any of the possible outputs ahead of time)

Comment: If the `readonly` part is not a problem then the only difference is the presence of those `?: undefined` fields. These fields aren't incorrect based on what the function returns, and they make the type more usable since they allow you to access `obj.str` without first checking the discriminant. Is there a specific reason you don't want them in the result type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript uses various heuristic rules when inferring types for values, which have been chosen to give desirable behavior for a wide range of use cases... but there will always be people and situations for which heuristics inevitably fail to meet expectations.

One such rule is that unions of object literals are inferred with optional `undefined` properties from other members of the union, as described in [the TypeScript 2.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#improved-type-inference-for-object-literals) and as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#19513](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19513).  This makes unions which would otherwise be hard to deal with (like `{foo: string} | {}`, which you can't index with `foo`) into [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) (like `{foo: string} | {foo?: undefined}`).  But unfortunately for your example this results in types you don't want.

---

*In general* I would advise someone to manually [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) the type they expected if inference doesn't work how they want, and the compiler will use that as [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing):

```
type DiscU = { type: "Quz"; str: "string"; } | { type: "Bar"; 1: "value" };

function fooAnnotate(num: number): DiscU {
    switch (num) {
        case 0: return { type: "Quz", str: 'string', }; 
        case 1: return { type: "Bar", 1: 'value' };
        default: throw new Error("Unknown discriminant: " + num);
    }
}
```

In the above, the output type is exactly what you want (because it's manually annotated), and you don't even need [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) because the desired type contextually types those object literals.

Unfortunately it is a requirement that you do not manually write out the type, so we will abandon this approach.

---

Because the behavior you don't like only happens when working with object literals, the "standard" workaround is the same one you would use to avoid [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks): assign the object literal to an intermediate variable, and then build the union with the variable instead:

```
function foo(num: number) {
    const case0 = { type: "Quz", str: 'string' } as const;
    const case1 = { type: "Bar", 1: 'value' } as const;
    switch (num) {
        case 0: return case0;
        case 1: return case1;
        default: throw new Error("Unknown discriminant" + num);
    }
}
/* function foo(num: number): {
    readonly type: "Quz";
    readonly str: "string";
} | {
    readonly type: "Bar";
    readonly 1: "value";
} */
```

This gives you the expected type (well, except that the properties are [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties); we will come back to that later...)

Hooray!  But this involved pre-computing the outputs for every possible input, and it is a requirement that you not do that.  So we will need to modify that approach.

---

One way to avoid pre-computing is to replace the value with an immediately-executed function that returns the value.  You can do this inline and even move it back into the `switch`/`case` statement:

```
function foo(num: number) {
    switch (num) {
        case 0: return (() => ({ type: "Quz", str: 'string' } as const))();
        case 1: return (() => ({ type: "Bar", 1: 'value' } as const))();
        default: throw new Error("Unknown discriminant" + num);
    }
}
/* function foo(num: number): {
    readonly type: "Quz";
    readonly str: "string";
} | {
    readonly type: "Bar";
    readonly 1: "value";
} */
```

The intermediate function manages to prevent the optional `undefined` properties, and meets the rest of your needs.  Hooray!

---

Well the properties are still `readonly`.  If that matters, you could change your immediately-executed function to a standalone function which  returns a non-`readonly` version of its input (using a [mapped type with `-readonly` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers)):

```
function foo(num: number) {
    const mutable = <T extends object>(o: T): { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] } => o;
    switch (num) {
        case 0: return mutable({ type: "Quz", str: 'string' } as const);
        case 1: return mutable({ type: "Bar", 1: 'value' } as const);
        default: throw new Error("Unknown discriminant" + num);
    }
}
/* function foo(num: number): {
    type: "Quz";
    str: "string";
} | {
    type: "Bar";
    1: "value";
} */
```

Now you have *exactly* the type you wanted, without needing to write it out or pre-compute any of the output values of the function.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZwMYFUoF4oG8qkgLigCIBFAVwC8iBuKBYAJ0KPobgDsBzGqAXygA+2XOAjMAQgEMGPAIzMAbpIA2ZCET7UAUFoBmZdkmBwA9uyi6TJgILt2J4JOAQAFOzIBbQu48AjCAwAlITwyGhYWlBRdADucMBIABZQbp6B2JHRWUiSCNAADIQMEMBkDOY4eGLE5FQANHSMhADkrByczQ282lnZudDyUMWl5cJVEtJEDYPNSqoQzZqZvVAAJhC6kmTKwITAiQwmMVDsEMcAogyHDC5EKOwA1vYx5quISGweHJLsu8RQAGoTmketFeFpwTp9IZjGYLFZrAgEHBOOwAMoQMDSJyuHzeTz+IIZbJmehQHJ5fIYMaiZi1KaNJhQVqMdqLfi5cmk4CgqJIbnk-qyamVWnEKQyaYtOZqdlQTn89j0XmxeJJFI+dIRFZ8-pQQpDEplcwUiD5FV9PJQQbDY2CvKyC3RdabbZ-faHY6nC5XEw3O6PZ6vd6fb6-DRAzUq8HggD0ACoLAYjKZzJYbEiUejMdjnKkvMC-AFgsTosVJKszMoQCICDVKDRloaK1Wa6xmG0uI3+EJtWWIC32NXa9UiBLG1ly5WhzXBkQZeptPx47GdHpk7C01YAHImc7SavnGU4-P4otEvtRBBxBLJfNapuWgpFI2jFwudLoAB8KVFddIDYNO2zKdh0fDyggXJKsAgSBB+Tq6laNqvuY76fj+Lh-qO45SsyC5ygq3KwfBj7OhsWw7HsBxHCcZxQJc1y3PcTxHMGyChuwPzABGhaBNGEJaAmSYwqm8ImLu+4MIex55nihaEiWl7NtOw7jPWVAqlOraMh2rJdkugillEWkziOEwyJpA4qbOigqGo3ZQCuUIbqJ6anvJxZGVBZIeGQji+Mo0CYAAPAAKlAEAAB7OOwqyQSYvgAFYQEYX4uCYhChYpUAALQmcOADaADSUAcFADwQCAJi6FAoUALqZcVdXgd+UAmCq15qnempeU++oviM5i+f5gWYWZ6kMsBLJsFwBGQYq9B8aRiEDANdrDZIAWuFh5kMjM+HgYR0FLTqazkW6VGerRPqMQGLEvGsIZwF8nHhoCvH8XGibQimcJuXJPgKYQSlqQBGlNsBLB6dwBm9k2oPjiqc4Lg5K5AA)